# Configuring the database for a new GeoNetwork Installaion

Tags: sql-server, database, geonetwork

I have some questions after reading the documentation for "[Configuring the database](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/4.0.x/en/install-guide/configuring-database.html)" for version 4.0.x GeoNetwork.

1. The documentation states: "***The database dialect is configured in /WEB-INF/config-node/srv.xml. Uncomment the dialect to use.***"  When you uncomment the dialect that you are using, should you comment the default H2 database?
2. For a first time installation, does GeoNetwork create the new database on your database server, or, should you create the database manually?

Comment: Be aware for SQL Server GeoNetwork doesn't include the JDBC driver, so you'll need to download from Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, comment the default H2 and have your preferred resource uncommented.
2. It will create the database for you, if your user has create database privileges.

Comment: I found that I had to create the database and then edit the user permissions.  GeoNetwork then added the tables to the database.

Comment: In addition to the steps in the instructions I had to edit the sqlserver.xml file located in WEB_INF\config-db\.  The following needed to be appended to the "jdbcURL" string: encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;